# Using ui-router in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I was working with `ngRoute` before I migrated to `ui-router`.

In my application I have this config :

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
    })
    .state('contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      templateUrl: 'views/contact.html'
    })
    .state('work', {
      url: '/work',
      templateUrl: 'views/work.html'
    })
    .state('work.top_authors', {
      url: '/top_authors',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/top_authors.html',
      controller: 'topAuthorsController'
    })
    .state('work.articles_evolution', {
      url: '/articles_evolution',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/articles_evolution.html',
      controller: 'articlesEvolutionController'
    })
    .state('work.top_organizations', {
      url: '/top_organizations',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/top_organizations.html',
      controller: 'topOrganizationsController'
    })
    .state('work.words_cloud', {
      url: '/words_cloud',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/words_cloud.html',
      controller: 'wordsCloudController'
    })
    .state('work.authors', {
      url: '/authors',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/authors.html',
      controller: 'authorsController'
    })
    .state('work.words', {
      url: '/words',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/words.html',
      controller: 'wordsController'
    })
    .state('work.jobs_offers', {
      url: '/jobs_offers',
      templateUrl: 'views/work/jobs_offers.html',
      controller: 'JobOffersByCounteryController'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

for the first 4 states I have no problems, but with the others who are the work state childs I have this problem :

So, when I click on (for example) `<a ui-sref="#/work/articles_evolution">Artciles Evolution</a>` I get this error in console :

```
Error: Could not resolve '#/work/articles_evolution' from state 'work'
```

but When I type the link in the browser : `http://localhost/dst-angular/app/#/work/articles_evolution` it works without problem.

How can I resolve this ?

**My second question is:**

in the html page `work` I have `<div ui-view></div>` which will be replaced by the template in the `ui-sref`, I want this page to contain some content and then when I click on the `ui-sref` to replace this content when the new template is embedded.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass state name in `ui-sref` instread of url:

```
<a ui-sref="work.articles_evolution">Artciles Evolution</a>
```

`ui-sref` directive will resolve url from state name and set as `href` attribute of anchor tag.